# Sorting algorithm which does not allow counting of elements

Tags: java, sorting

I have seen acrosss in a company interview test this question, but i am not clear about the question first. Could you people clarify my doubt ?

> Question : Write a program to sort an integer array which contains Only 0's,1's and 2's. Counting of elements not allowed, you are expected to do it in O(n) time complexity.
>
> Ex Array : {2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0}

Comment: You have to count the elements, otherwise you don't know when you are done?

Comment: What is the best suitable sorting algorthim to achieve this

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Because there are so few values in the array, just *count* how many of each type there are and use that to repopulate your array. We also make use of the fact that the values are consecutive from 0 up - making it match the typical java int loop.

The whole sorting algorithm requires only three lines of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] array = { 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0 };

    // Line 1: Define some space to hold the totals
    int[] counts = new int[3]; // To store the (3) different totals

    // Line 2: Get the total of each type
    for (int i : array) counts[i]++;

    // Line 3: Write the appropriate number of each type consecutively back into the array:
    for (int i = 0, start = 0; i < counts.length; start += counts[i++]) Arrays.fill(array, start, start + counts[i], i);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

At no time did we refer to `array.length`, no care how long the array was. It iterated through the array touching each element just once, making this algorithm O(n) as required.

Comment: I read that as "counting the number of elements", not "counting the number of each element type". I can see how you could read it that way.

Comment: I've posted another version that *doesn't* count the elements :)

Comment: Relax ppl - see my other answer, which would count as acceptable no matter the interpretation of question

Comment: @Bohemian That’s irrelevant. We’re not against you personally, we’re against this answer being accepted, since it fails the prerequisites, but the OP seems not to realise this. Your other answer is totally fine (the code, that is; the explanation is wrong).

Answer (score 10):

Output to a linked list.

- Remember the beginning of the list.
- Remember the position where the 1s start.
- Remember the end of the list.

Run through the whole array.

- If you encounter a 0, add it to the first position of the linked list.
- If you encounter a 1, add it after the position of the 1.
- If you encounter a 2, add it at the end of the list.

HTH

Raku

Answer (score 4):

Instead of blasting you with yet another unintelligible pseudo-code, I’ll give you the name of the problem: this problem is known as the [*Dutch national flag problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem) (first proposed by Edsgar Dijkstra) and can be solved by a three-ways merge (see the PHP code in the first answer which solves this, albeit very inefficiently).

A more efficient in-place solution of the threeways merge is described in Bentley’s and McIlroy’s seminal paper [*Engineering a Sort Function*](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.14.8162). It uses four indices to delimit the ranges of the intermediate array, which has the unsorted values in the middle, the 1s at both edges, and the 0s and 2s in-between:

[image: threeways merge]

After having established this invariant, the `=` parts (i.e. the 1s) are swapped back into the middle.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you mean by "no counting allowed".

One simple way to do this would be to have a new empty array, then look for 0's, appending them to the new array. Repeat for 1's then 2's and it's sorted in O(n) time.

But this is more-or-less a radix sort. It's like we're counting the 0's then 1's then 2's, so I'm not sure if this fits your criteria.

---

Edit: we could do this with only O(1) extra memory by keeping a pointer for our insertion point (starting at the start of the array), and scanning through the array for 0's, swapping each 0 with the element where the pointer is, and incrementing the pointer. Then repeat for 1's, 2's and it's still O(n).

Java implementation:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sort 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] array = {2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0};
        sort(array);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    public static void sort(int[] array)
    {
        int pointer = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
            {
                if(array[j] == i)
                {
                    int temp = array[pointer];
                    array[pointer] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                    pointer++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gives output:

> [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]

Comment: Yes. It's sort of what I was thinking as well. But thinking about it, sorting generalyy means rearranging in place, not copying to a new array. Of course you could also say that copying back the copy to the original array still makes it O(n).

Comment: Added an edit to do this using swaps and O(1) extra memory instead of a new array

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it's php, but it seems O(n) and could be easily written in java :)

```
$arr = array(2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0);

$tmp = array(array(),array(),array());
foreach($arr as $i){
    $tmp[$i][] = $i;
}
print_r(array_merge($tmp[0],$tmp[1],$tmp[2]));
```

Comment: Inefficient as hell but this is the only code here that’s actually understandable and it showcases very well the basic idea that is required to solve the problem, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

In O(n), pseudo-code:

```
def sort (src):
    # Create an empty array, and set pointer to its start.

    def dest as array[sizeof src]
    pto = 0

    # For every possible value.

    for val in 0, 1, 2:
        # Check every position in the source.

        for pfrom ranges from 0 to sizeof(src):
            # And transfer if matching (includes update of dest pointer).
            if src[pfrom] is val:
                dest[pto] = val
                pto = pto + 1

    # Return the new array (or transfer it back to the source if desired).

    return dest
```

This is basically iterating over the source list three times, adding the elements if they match the value desired on this pass. But it's still O(n).

The equivalent Java code would be:

```
class Test {
    public static int [] mySort (int [] src) {
        int [] dest = new int[src.length];
        int pto = 0;

        for (int val = 0; val < 3; val++)
            for (int pfrom = 0; pfrom < src.length; pfrom++)
                if (src[pfrom] == val)
                    dest[pto++] = val;
        return dest;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int [] arr1 = {2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0};
        int [] arr2 = mySort (arr1);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++)
            System.out.println ("Array[" + i + "] = " + arr2[i]);
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
Array[0] = 0
Array[1] = 0
Array[2] = 0
Array[3] = 1
Array[4] = 1
Array[5] = 1
Array[6] = 2
Array[7] = 2
Array[8] = 2
Array[9] = 2
```

---

But seriously, if a potential employer gave me this question, I'd state straight out that I could answer the question if they wish, but that the *correct* answer is to just use `Array.sort`. Then if, and *only* if, there is a performance problem with that method and the specific data sets, you could investigate a faster way.

And that faster way would almost certainly involve counting, despite what the requirements were. You don't hamstring your developers with arbitrary limitations. Requirements should specify *what* is required, not *how.*

If you answered this question to me in this way, I'd hire you on the spot.

Comment: Question is tagged [java]. How about rendering this in java?

Comment: @Bohemian, I'm usually more interested in algorithms than specific code translations, especially since this question is only for one of those perennially silly exercises from hirers who don't know much about how to evaluate potential candidates. But, as you wish...

Answer (score 0):

This answer *doesn't* count the elements.

Because there are so few values in the array, just count how many of each type there are and use that to repopulate your array. We also make use of the fact that the values are consecutive from 0 up - making it match the typical java int loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Integer[] array = { 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0 };
    List<Integer>[] elements = new ArrayList[3]; // To store the different element types

    // Initialize the array with new lists
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) elements[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // Populate the lists
    for (int i : array) elements[i].add(i);

    for (int i = 0, start = 0; i < elements.length; start += elements[i++].size())
        System.arraycopy(elements[i].toArray(), 0, array, start, elements[i].size());

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Push and Pull have a constant complexity!

1. > Push each element into a priority queue
2. > Pull each element to indices 0...n

(:

Comment: “Push and Pull have a constant complexity” – no they don’t. Hence this answer is wrong.

Comment: its only a 0 1 or 2! it is constant time.. with a v.small modification

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one pass, placing each encountered element to it's final position:

```
void sort012(int* array, int len) {
    int* p0 = array;
    int* p2 = array + len;
    for (int* p = array; p <= p2; ) {
        if (*p == 0) {
            std::swap(*p, *p0);
            p0++;
            p++;
        } else if (*p == 2) {
            std::swap(*p, *p2);
            p2--;
        } else {
            p++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ps: it should be easy to transform this to java.

Comment: Except that without explanation this code is completely unintelligible.

Comment: It's actually a dutch national flag solution.. but seeing that solutions get votes with 3 passes or using a hash I doubt it's worth the effort :/